# Does Stack Overflow Careers use an Applicant Tracking System?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

After I upload my resume for a job posting, how does the recruiter see it on their end? Will they simply see my resume or will there be an applicant tracking software that makes inaccurate and unwarranted conclusions from my resume?

Comment: What the recruiting company does with CVs they receive is really up to them.

Answer (score 1):

How employers use Careers is up to them: some accept resumés by email, others send you through an external system and we also provide messaging and tracking systems within Careers itself.

If the employer is using Careers itself all we do is provide a way for employers to review resumés; that will either be by sending them an email notifying that they have a new resumé to review, via their dashboard or via an integration into a third party system like Greenhouse.

As a side note - use of an applicant tracking system doesn't imply that the system automatically categorises and discards resumés using some machine learning algorithm - they're generally used to track the progress of an applicant through a particular process.